# How to Insert to database from loop Using PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

The problem occurs when I insert without data. So I want your help in solving this problem.

This is my file:
students.php

```
        <form id="student_form" method="POST"   action="">
<?php
    if(mysql_num_rows($q)>0){           

                ?>


    <table   border="0" dir="ltr" align="center"cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' >

        <tr> <th>Student ID</th><th>Name</th><th>AVG</th><th>Joining Year</th><th>Message</th><th>Sending Message</th> </tr>

        <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)){ ?>
        <tr>

            <td id="stud_id[]"> <?php echo $row['studant_ID']; ?></td>
            <td> <?php echo $row['studant_Name']; ?></td>
            <td> <?php echo $row['Average']; ?></td>
            <td> <?php echo $row['year']; ?></td>
            <td> <input id="message1[]" name="message1[]" type="text" size="25px" /></td>
            <td><input name="submit[]" id="submit[]" type="submit"  value="Send"  /> </td>
        </tr>

<?php }}
```

and this is my insert file:
insert_message.php

```
if (isset($_POST['message1']) && $_POST['message1']!='') {

            $addss = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['message1']);
        } 

if (isset($_POST['stud_id']) && $_POST['stud_id']!='') {

            $std_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['stud_id']);
        }        


//####################################################################### 

 $query1 = "INSERT INTO `message` (`rcvrid`, `senderid`, `msg`) VALUES ('$std_id', '22011111', '$addss'); ";
 mysql_query($query1);
```

I connect between two file by *jquery* and *ajax*.

```
<script>

 $("#student_form").on("submit", function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "insert_message.php",
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#inner_contant").append(data+"<br/>");//instead this line here you can call some function to read database values and display
                    },
                });
            });


</script>
```

Comment: `$_POST['message1']` is an array. And `$_POST['stud_id']` doesn't exists.

Comment: How i can fix this ?

Comment: Show js for ajax request.

Comment: add name attribute: <td id="stud_id[]" name="stud_id[]"> <?php echo $row['studant_ID']; ?></td>

Comment: Only one record insert in database when press the button

Comment: thank you for your answer @RomanPerekhrest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the form from the page

```
<tr>

            <td id="stud_id"> <?php echo $row['studant_ID']; ?>
              <input type="hidden" name="stud_id" value="<?php echo $row['studant_ID']; ?>"/>
            </td>
            <td> <?php echo $row['studant_Name']; ?></td>
            <td> <?php echo $row['Average']; ?></td>
            <td> <?php echo $row['year']; ?></td>
            <td> <input id="message1" name="message1" type="text" size="25px" /></td>
            <td><button class="submit" type="submit" />Send </button> </td>
        </tr>
```

second:
your js should look like this:

```
$(".submit").on("click", function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "insert_message.php",
                    data: {stud_id:$(this).closest('tr').find('input[name="stud_id"]').val(),message1:$(this).closest('tr').find('input[name="message1"]').val()},
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#inner_contant").append(data+"<br/>");//instead this line here you can call some function to read database values and display
                    },
                });
            });
```

In  insert_message.php
you need to echo a message to see if you where succesful in updating the database

```
echo json_encode(array('message'=>'Data updated/Error'));
```

Comment: It seems everything is okay but it does not go to the page insert_massage, When I press the button

Comment: the data isn't updateed in the database?,what does the network & console display?

Comment: i use localhost Wampserver and Firfox browser

Comment: in the network tab how does the xhr request look like?

Comment: Setting `form` tag in a `tr` is **invalid**. Browser rebuilds it and your form is not what you expect.

Comment: how i can fix it ?@u_mulder

Comment: parent of `submit` is `td`. You won't find there any `input` there.

Comment: the same problem insert without data

Comment: it insert student id but it does not insert the message

Comment: just insert student id first row, the second or another row not working

Comment: I want to thank you for your time and effort and everything and I wish you to be the best @madalin ivascu

Comment: I want to thank you for your time and effort and everything and I wish you to be the best @madalinivascu

Answer (score 1):

First of all - all data passed to server in a `$_POST` array is taken from input fields with `name` attribute (unless you have some custom js handlers).

So

```
<td id="stud_id[]"> <?php echo $row['studant_ID']; ?></td>
```

does **nothing**.

If you want to store `studant_ID` somehow - use `hidden` field for example:

```
<td>
    <input type="hidden" name="stud_id[]" value="<?php echo $row['studant_ID']; ?>" />
</td>
```

Next - what do you want from this buttons:

```
<input name="submit[]" id="submit[]" type="submit" value="Send" />
```

As they are all belong to one `form` they will do the same - send all fields to server. If you want every `submit` button send to server only a pair `student_id, message` you have to create a `form` for each pair (or do some js-handlers). Otherwise, on your server you'll have:

- `$_POST['stud_id']` array of **all students ids** from form
- `$_POST['message1']` array of **all messages** from form

If you want to process them all - do a `foreach`:

```
foreach ($_POST['stud_id'] as $key => $id) {
     // find the message
     $msg = $_POST['message1'][$key];
     $query1 = "INSERT INTO `message` (`rcvrid`, `senderid`, `msg`)    VALUES ('$id', '22011111', '$msg'); ";
     mysql_query($query1);
}
```

And of course you should remove `mysql_` functions and use newer apis - `PDO` or `mysqli`

Comment: I want to send a message to one student by pressing the button, and to insert the message and studant_id to the database.

Comment: As I already said - either create a separate `form` for each pair, or create some js-handler to send only one pair of fields at a time.

Comment: If you have time could you help me in that؟